# What's pooling in the spread plate technique?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

"Distributing the organisms by rotating the spreader rather than the plate tends to cause more pooling of the inoculum."
https://asm.org/ASM/media/Protocol-Images/Preparing-Spread-Plates-Protocols.pdf?ext=.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forming a [pool](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pool) (second definition in link); forming a small amount of liquid on a surface. *A la* "*I knocked my cup over and the coffee formed a small pool on my bench*"

Basically this results in a concentration of the organisms in one area, rather than an evenly distributed spread.